# Alternative to multiprocessing.manager in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've been managing a program that uses multiprocessing.manager due to some requirements, however we have been getting a steady amount of errors such as timeouts, invalid references and other similar errors.

Now I'm curious if there is a more developed alternative to multiprocessing.manager that has better overall reliability and less state tracking on the client side.

I've tried Google on the subject but due to the odd combination of keywords I only receive bogus results.

Our usual use case is similar to this:

```
def connect():
  manager = CustomManager(address=manager_address, authkey=manager_authkey)
  manager.connect()
  session = manager.session()
  return session

connect().some_function()
```

Comment: Do you have any code that can reproduce these errors. Something that can do a stress test on the manager maybe. There are many ways to do inter-process communication so I just want to know what scenarios are giving you these issues.

Comment: @MarwanAlsabbagh Added a snippet of code we use to connect and how we often use the manager.

Comment: I think what @MarwanAlsabbagh meant is that the question is too vague. What is the specific functionality required, and what is the actual error encountered? There are a few alternatives to multiprocessing.manager, but they are varied and their fit depends on your specific needs. My experience with the above is that the mp managers are good for initializing local proxy objects (e.g. Queue, Dict, etc.,) but are too slow as function hosts (such as in your example) if you use these functions frequently.

Comment: The use case is really more as a process API, for example one of the processes running is an IRC client and we use the manager for manipulating the client from other processes.

Comment: That's correct @Nisan.H I was looking for what are the requirements and the errors being faced. I put forth an answer I hope it is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the question and your comments, If you want something more solid to manage processes there are better alternatives to using the multiprocessing module. Below are two options you might want to explore:

**Gearman**

This is a description of the [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) project.

> Gearman provides a generic application framework to farm out work to
>   other machines or processes that are better suited to do the work

Instagram has workers written in python and uses Gearman to run these jobs in the background. You can read about it in the Task Queue section of this [What Powers Instagram](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/13649370142/what-powers-instagram-hundreds-of-instances-dozens-of) post.

**Celery: Distributed Task Queue**

[Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) is an asynchronous task queue based on distributed message passing, it is focused on real-time operation. It is really popular in the Django community.

Both solutions are very scalable and used extensively so you will find a lot of documentation and tutorials on how to use them. They are more involved though so there will be more of an initial learning curve. But I think it might be worth the time investment if you are hitting the limit of multiprocessing.